# Грамотно объединить IF() и MIN, MAX в одном SQL запросе

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных

Друзья, есть 2 таблицы (товар и скидки)
нужно выбирать MIN и MAX цены, учитывая, что у товара еще и может быть скидка
т.е делаю примерно так

```
select 
IF(s.status, s.specials_new_products_price, p.products_price) AS MAX(products_price),
IF(s.status, s.specials_new_products_price, p.products_price) AS MIN(products_price), 
c.parent_id, 
c.categories_id
from ".TABLE_PRODUCTS_TO_CATEGORIES." p2c, 
    ".TABLE_PRODUCTS." p 
LEFT JOIN " . TABLE_SPECIALS . " s 
    ON (p.products_id = s.products_id)....
```

Но что то не то.
Без IF() раньше был просто запрос

```
select 
    MAX(p.products_price),
    MIN(p.products_price), 
    c.parent_id, 
    c.categories_id 
from ".TABLE_PRODUCTS_TO_CATEGORIES." p2c, 
    ".TABLE_PRODUCTS." p, 
    ".TABLE_CATEGORIES." c 
where p.products_status = '1'....
```

и ниже получал значения

```
$maxpr = $res_maxpr['MAX(p.products_price)'];
$minpr = $res_maxpr['MIN(p.products_price)'];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для того, чтобы получить максимальное/минимальное значение из ряда данных нужно поместить функцию IF внутрь функции MAX или MIN:

```
SELECT MIN(IF(s.status, s.specials_new_products_price, p.products_price)) AS min_price ...
```

При этом, если FROM и WHERE секция запроса были составлены корректно, их можно не менять.